# Access to the number as an object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Can anyone describe to which mechanism relates this behavior:
When i try access to property of number

```
2.constructor
```

I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`

When i try access to property of number in this way

```
(1).constructor
```

I get

```
ƒ Number() { [native code] }
```

Comment: because it is a decimal place. Trying to find the duplicate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need another dot to distinguish the first decimal separator from a dot as a property accessor.

```js
console.log(2..constructor);
```